# How to refresh a stacktable js after underlying table is filtered in mobile

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter, stacktable.js

I am using dc.js and crossfilter.js to make a dashboard. When moving to mobile I turn the data table responsive with stacktable. However in mobile when I click on various filters, the stacktable doesn't update since it is a copy of the underlying table. Is there a way to refresh a stacktable based on the main table. Or remove stacktable and add again to reflect the newest table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with [stacktable.js](https://github.com/johnpolacek/stacktable.js/) but my guess is that it isn't noticing when d3 modifies the table underneath it (which is good because there are a lot of modifications).

My guess is to reinitialize stacktable each time the dc.js data table is redrawn. You can use the `pretransition` event for this. (A number of the [other events](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#basemixinon--basemixin) could work, too, but this seems simplest.

Something like:

```
dataTable.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
    $('#your-data-table').stacktable({your options});
});
```

Comment: Wow, finally got it after things weren't working. Realized I needed the beta.11 and I was on .1. I also had to remove the existing table to re-add it as you have shown. So I ended up with this    .on("pretransition", function() {$('.small-only').remove(); $('#data-table').stacktable(); })